# API Unit Testing (Test Endpoints vs. Test Everything)

Tags: api, unit-testing, laravel-4

we are building an API using Laravel, and we are facing an essential question:

Are we supposed to test everything (every method in every Model, Controller, and any other class)? or just test the API endpoints since testing endpoints means that everything else will be tested, because an API endpoint is using a Controller's method, that is in turn using a Model's method!

In fact I tend to the later one which is testing endpoints will help you test everything else, but I need to be sure that this is the right thing to do.

**Edit:**

Consider the following two points:

- testing endpoints means that I have to send an HTTP request and wait for the response to see if it is what I need, and that may be very bad con for this method.
- testing everything means that I have to find some way to mock up laravel request and its headers, and that may be very bad con for this method.

Any hints or comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arguments and supporters exist for both sides. I suspect there are as many opinions on this subject as there are developers doing any form of developer testing.

In a nutshell:

- Unit tests put greater pressure on your design. Bad code will hurt more if you are testing at the unit level.
- Unit tests allow you to pinpoint problems more accurately, since they test each unit of work in isolation. If a unit test fails, you know where to look for the problem. If an integrated test blows up, you know something's wrong but typically have to start debugging to find the actual problem.

I like the phrase twitter user [@everzet](https://twitter.com/everzet/status/572661259356794880) recently used:

> When they're green, all tests look the same. It's when they're red you
>   see the real difference.

On the other hand, integrated tests provide more freedom when refactoring. If you test only at the API level, you can change the entire implementation without affecting your tests. If you test at the unit level, a refactoring might mean you have to update/rewrite a whole lot of tests.

Comment: so you think building both tests is better? if yes, how should test models in laravel if they depend on request headers for example??

Comment: It all depends on your current context: the project, the discipline/maturity of your colleague developers, etc. If you ask me right now, I'd definitely test everything at the unit level and have very few end-to-end tests to verify that the system is actually wired up correctly. This ties in nicely with the concept of Cohn's [testing pyramid](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html). The fact remains that the higher-level your tests are, the more costly they become to maintain.

Comment: thank you @prgmtc , you opened my eyes to something else as well, that may be I am failing to write the unit test because the units are not satisfying the principle of single responsibility , I will accept your answer :D